# jquery slideonlyone function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using jquery slideonlyone function. I am having problems implementing an expanding/collapsing image(Plus.png)(Minus.png) change when clicked on. this is my jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes2"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).find("img").attr({src:"Minus.png"}).slideDown(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).find("img").attr({src:"Plus.png"}).slideUp(600);
      }
 });
}</script>


<table><tr>
  <td>
     <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
        <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes1');" ><img src="images/faq_cuts/Plus_Circle.png";/>slide this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div name="newboxes2" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px;">Div #1</div>
  </td>
  <td>
     <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
        <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes2');" ><img src="images/faq_cuts/Plus_Circle.png";/>slide this one only</a>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have any images in your html.

Also, you are using `attr` incorrectly.  If you want to set the `src` of an image it would be `.attr("src","Minus.png")`.

Comment: Alright mate, i tried that but didn't work.                            `<script type="text/javascript">
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes2"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).find("img")attr({"src","images/faq_cuts/Minus_Circle.png"}).slideDown(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).find("img").attr("src","images/faq_cuts/Plus_Circle.png"}).slideUp(600);
      }
 });
}
</script> 
`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Could you point out to me where those syntax are? I am very novice with jquery